# Communication lost in thread

Tags: c++, stdthread, asio

My question is simple, I have made a server with Boost Asio.
It works well. The problem is when I launch std::thread, I cannot communicate anymore with the server.

Could you tell me why ? because I don't really get it.
Thanks !

here is my function who handle what I received :

```
void    Server::handleCmd()
{
        if (isClientExist() == false) {
                addClient();
        }
        _vTmpString = Tools::splitString(_cmd, ' ');
        _idCmd = Tools::stringToInt(_vTmpString[0]);
        switch (_idCmd)
        {
                case CREATEROOM:
                        createRoom();
                        break;
                case DISCONNECTION:
                        delClient();
                        break;
                case GETROOM:
                        getVectorRoomsForClients();
                        break;
                case JOINROOM:
                        joinRoom();
                        break;
                case LEAVEROOM:
                        leaveRoom();
                        break;
                case STARTROOM:
                        startGame();
                        break;
        }
}
```

the function who launches the thread :

```
void    Server::startGame()
{
        _vTmpString = Tools::splitString(_cmd, ' ');
        if (_vTmpString.size() != 2 && Tools::isNumber(_vTmpString[1]) == true)
                return;
        _tmpCmd = _vTmpString[0];
        _tmpIdRoom = std::stoi(_vTmpString[1]);
        if (_vTmpString.size() == 2 && _tmpCmd == "startroom" && _tmpIdRoom < 10000) {
                sendMsg("OK\n");
                std::cout << "CLIENT " << _remoteEndPoint << " ASKS FOR STARTING THE ROOM " << CYAN << _tmpIdRoom << DEFAULT << " : " << GREEN << "OK" << DEFAULT << std::endl;
                std::thread     launchGame(&Server::gameLoop, this, _tmpIdRoom);

                launchGame.join();
        } else {
                sendMsg("KO\n");
                std::cout << "CLIENT " << _remoteEndPoint << "ASKS FOR STARTING THE ROOM " << CYAN << _tmpIdRoom << DEFAULT << " : " << GREEN << "KO" << DEFAULT << std::endl;
        }
}
```

and once I'm in the the thread, if i try to send any known commands, the server doesn't response anymore. the _cmd is blocked on the last one I sent before starting the server, it means "startroom".

Comment: There is not enough information (nor code) in this question to be able to answer. Please post a [mcve] and be more explicit about what you expect and what you observe.

Answer (score 1):

`launchGame.join()` blocks until the thread terminates. And since the thread apparently runs a game loop, it won't terminate for a while. It makes little sense to join with it at this point.

Comment: hello, what do you mean by "joint with it" ?

Comment: I mean call `join()` method. That method doesn't return until the thread terminates, so `startGame` is probably not a right place to call it. As written, it's more like `startGameAndWaitForItToFinish`